# Is it possible to replicate this animation to any theme?

Tags: css

I stumbled upon this theme called "Erase" by TomKirk [preview](http://tomkirkthemes.tumblr.com/th/erase/1) and [code](http://pastebin.com/JHLkSgFa#)

I was wondering if it is possible to replicate the same animation when your cursor hovers over a link like the notes or the reblog button just by plugining in a code to the css.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the hovering color change can easily be reproduced for your own applications.

I recommend taking a look at some of the CSS3 docs with regards to transitions. There is some good information about CSS3 transition located over @ [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions) which can be seen [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions).

For links to change color on hover, you'll be looking for something similar to;

```css
a {
  transition: color .5s ease 0s;
  -webkit-transition: color .5s ease 0s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
a:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <a>reblog</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope that can help you out! :D